# stanfordcorenlp INFO:root:Waiting until the server is available

Tags: java, python, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use [pycorenlp](https://pypi.org/project/pycorenlp/) but it's infinitely printing the following line:
INFO:root:Waiting until the server is available

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first start a CoreNLP server running. See the instructions under "Usage" here: https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp